# What is meaning of gettext('Some Text') in Openstack

Tags: angularjs, openstack, jinja2, openstack-horizon

What is meaning of gettext('Some text are written')?. I am using openstack, there they have use gettext(), please see the following link [openstack on github](https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/master/openstack_dashboard/static/dashboard/launch-instance/source/source.js#L80-#l96)

I want to know meaning of it, i**f they are assigning the text to the variable why they didn't use just assignment opearator**

```
$scope.label = {
  title: gettext('Instance Details'),
  instanceName: gettext('Instance Name'),
  availabilityZone: gettext('Availability Zone'),
  instance_count: gettext('Count'),
};
```

Comment: that depends on what `gettext` is

Comment: @ArunPJohny , thanks for replay, could you elaborate more on it..

Comment: `gettext` is a function... it should be defined somewhere in your code.

Comment: There is no gettext method in angular nor in javascript. I guess it is something related to localization. You can trace into this function in chrome developer tools to see its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably related to localization. Function `gettext` is looking for translation of provided arguments and display them in selected locale.

As an example of translation service in angular, check https://angular-translate.github.io/